# Restricting Rails routes to actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Lets say I have an UsersController that contains an action #new. In my routes file I map with the following:

```
match 'signup', to: 'users#new'
```

This action can now be accessed by both /signup and /users/new. How do I restrict it to only the custom route.

I apologize if this has been answered, but am new to this. I've searched, but haven't found the answer. Possibly due to my not knowing how to concisely phrase this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can exempt the `new` route from the users resource, and replace it with your custom route:

```
resources :users, except: [:new]
get 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: "new_user"
```

Resulting in:

```
    users GET        /users(.:format)               users#index
          POST       /users(.:format)               users#create
edit_user GET        /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
     user GET        /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
          PUT        /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
          DELETE     /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
 new_user GET        /signup(.:format)              users#new
```

Comment: As usual, that was simple and beautiful. Thanks for the help. Now I hear convention says to stick with resourceful routes, but does this just mean at the controller level? Is it more proper to use the resources routes as opposed to creating custom routes?

Comment: Yeah, conventionally you should stick to resourceful routes. Given that you're creating a new route with the `new_user` name, all of the standard resourceful magic *should* apply, but in general, sticking to conventions reduces the chance of surprises.